# Query the Most recent Record based on Status and CreatedDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table

```
Email               Status                  CreatedDate(mm/dd/yyyy)
abc@gmail.com       Open                     10/02/2018
abc@gmail.com       Closed                   10/06/2018
abc@gmail.com       Prospect                 10/04/2018
xyz@gmail.com       closed                   10/21/2018
xyz@gmail.com       closed                   10/01/2018
123@mail.com        Open                     10/04/2018
123@gmail.com       Open                     10/03/2018
123@gmail.com       closed                   10/02/2018
123@gmail.com       closed                   10/01/2018
```

Output

```
abc@gmail.com       Prospect                 10/04/2018
xyz@gmail.com       closed                   10/21/2018
123@gmail.com       open                     10/04/2018
```

The above output is based on the following conditions:

1. Take the unique record of each email.
2. **Condition 1** suppose"abc@gmail.com" has three records and if the 
   status = "prospect" found select that record irrespective to 
   createdDate and any other status.
3. **Condition 2** Suppose "xyz@gmail.com" has two records and both are of 
   status = "Closed" than check the CreatedDate and select the latest 
    date.
4. **Condition 3** Suppose "123@gmail.com" has four records and two of them are in open status and two are in Closed, we should take the open status and select based on the latest created date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()` in a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by email
                                order by (case when status = 'prospect' then 1
                                               when status = 'open' then 2
                                               when status = 'closed' then 3
                                               else 4
                                          end), CreatedDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also express this without the subquery:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by email
                            order by (case when status = 'prospect' then 1
                                           when status = 'open' then 2
                                           when status = 'closed' then 3
                                           else 4
                                      end), CreatedDate desc
                           )
```

Comment: Can I put IN operator instead of "="because i have the similar status which can be treated as Open.

Comment: Once I checked the execution plans of both approaches and found out, that the second, my former favourite due to its *coolness factor* performs the sort twice and is behind in performance after the *sub-query-approach*... Don't know if this is true in any case...

Comment: @Shnugo . . . To be honest, I think the correlated subquery approach often has the best performance.  It is a bit cumbersome in this case, so for complex conditions, `row_number()` is easier to express.